# Enviar mail desde Bash con imágenes

Tags: bash, email, crontab, cron

Tengo que armar un script en Linux que se ejecute todos los dias y, en el caso de que haya un cumpleaños, enviarle a todos los empleados un mail informando ese cumpleaños.

Esta parte me funciona perfecto, el problema que tengo es en el apartado del diseño:

Yo envío el mail como html. Lo armé en 3 partes: un footer un body y un header, donde el archivo de body tiene todo el codigo que le voy agregando por medio de las distintas consultas que hago y el header tiene el html hasta la etiqueta `<body>` y el footer el html desde la etiqueta `</body>`.

El código es funcional, si yo ejecuto el sh desde mi máquina se ve perfectamente la imagen de felicitaciones, el nombre del cumpleañero en rojo y su sector en negro. AHORA, cuando se ejecuta mediante el cron, me llega la informacion pero sin color, sin la imagen y sin el saludo de cumpleaños (Que se encuentra en el archivo header como `<h2>`).

¿Alguien sabe que puede llegar a ser el problema?

Lo ejecuto con este comando:

```
mail -s "$(echo -e "$ASUNTO \nContent-Type: text/html")" $DESTINATARIO < cuerpo.html
```

Comment: que usas para el envio mutt,  mailx ? cual es tu script?

Comment: @Rastalovely Uso el siguiente comando:

Comment: @Rastalovely mail -s "$(echo -e "$ASUNTO \nContent-Type: text/html")"  $DESTINATARIO  < cuerpo.html asi que uso MAIL para enviar emails!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el comando que usas para enviar el correo, debes agregar la ruta completa hacia tu archivo `cuerpo.html`, y de la misma manera, adentro de ese archivo, agregar la ruta completa hacia tu archivo de imagen.

La diferencia es que cuando ejecutas el comando de envío de correo "manualmente" desde tu línea de comandos, estás ubicado en la ruta donde tienes los archivos involucrados, pero cuando se ejecuta desde el cron, la ruta de ejecución no es la misma, para asegurar que estamos enviando los archivos, debemos incluir la ruta completa.

Espero que esto resuelva tu problema.

Comment: Hola Jesus! Te hago una consulta, el problema me lo da tambien con el html, por ejemplo si lo pongo en tablas me ignora el html pero si me respeta las negritas y letras a color...es por el mismo problema ?

Comment: Era eso! Solucionado, gracias!